# New object in Entity Framework - problems with primary key

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

In my database I have a `Vehicle` table with a primary key. I am creating a new `Vehicle` object using

```
new Vehicle();
```

and updating the properties of vehicle appropriately.

When I try to do a

```
genesisContext.Vehicles.AddObject(vehicle);
```

The first time the table is successfully updated and the primary key is 0. On all subsequent occasions I get an error saying that the key is not unique

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'VEHICLES_PK'. Cannot insert
>   duplicate key in object 'dbo.Vehicles'.\r\nThe statement has been
>   terminated.

(*presumably because the primary key set by the EF is still 0*)

I was under the understanding that the EF intelligently works out primary keys so why is this happening??

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have two choices:

- either you let the database handle the primary key, by specifying the VehicleID as `INT IDENTITY(1,1)` - in that case, SQL Server will automagically assign unique and individual numbers, and EF will be fine with that
- or you handle it yourself, e.g. you have to find a way in your app to come up with unique vehicle ID numbers.

EF out of the box has nothing in it to magically dispense unique numbers for primary keys - if you thought that, it was a misconception.

Marc

Comment: and if you handle yourself, you need to design around possible problems with multiple users insterting at the same time. I far prefer to have an autogenerated value.

Comment: Yes, absolutely - that's why it's really best left to the database to make sure ID's are unique!

Comment: Thanks - yes the problem was that I had not set the identity column in the db

Answer (score 1):

You can assign the new id on `SavingChanges` events of `ObjectContext`

```
objectContext.SavingChanges += new EventHandler(objectContext_SavingChanges);
```