# Adding Item with Many-to-Many Relationship In Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, exception, primary-key

I am getting a primary key violation error when I attempt to add an item with a many-to-many relationship:

I have two classes - Articles and Tags which have a many-to-many relationship :

```
public class Article
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public   ICollection<Tag>  Tags { get; set; }
}

public class Tag
{ 
    [Key]
    public string UrlSlug { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Article> Articles{ get; set; }
}
```

When I add a new Article I allow the user to input any Tags and then I want to create a new Tag if the Tag isn't created yet in the database or add the Tag to the Tags collection of the Article object if the Tag already exists.

Therefore when I am creating the new Article object I call the below function:

```
public static Tag GetOrLoadTag(String tagStr)
{
    string tagUrl = Tag.CreateTagUrl(tagStr);
    var db = new SnippetContext();
    var tagFromDb = from tagdummy in db.Tags.Include(x => x.Articles)
                    where tagdummy.UrlSlug == tagUrl
                    select tagdummy;
    if (tagFromDb.FirstOrDefault() != null)
    { return tagFromDb.FirstOrDefault(); }
    else
    {
        //create and send back a new Tag
    }
}
```

This function basically checks if there is an available Tag in the database and if so returns that Tag which is then added to the Tag collection of the Article object using article.Tags.Add().

However, when I attempt to save this using the below code I get a Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint error

```
 db.Entry(article).State = EntityState.Modified;
 db.SaveChanges();
```

I can't figure out how I should go about just creating a relationship between the Article and the already existing Tag.

Comment: can you please provide more details and the full code?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use the same context instance for the whole processing of your operation and your life will be much easier:

```
using (var ctx = new MyContext())
{
    Article article = ctx.Articles.Single(a => a.Id == articleId);
    Tag tag = ctx.Tags.SingleOrDefault(t => t.UrlSlug == tagUrl);
    if (tag == null) 
    {
       tag = new Tag() { ... }
       ctx.Tags.AddObject(tag);
    }

    article.Tags.Add(tag);
    ctx.SaveChanges();
}
```

If you don't want to load the article from database (that query is redundant if you know that article exists) you can use:

```
using (var ctx = new MyContext())
{
    Article article = new Article() { Id = articleId };
    ctx.Articles.Attach(article);

    Tag tag = ctx.Tags.SingleOrDefalut(t => t.UrlSlug == tagUrl);
    if (tag == null) 
    {
       tag = new Tag() { ... }
       ctx.Tags.AddObject(tag);
    }

    article.Tags.Add(tag);
    ctx.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Thanks that did the trick. I guess a lot of folks get tripped up on Entity Framework by using a different Context. The problem is that doing everything in the same operation kinda goes against how we normally program a DAL with different operations. The best bet seems to be passing the context as a ref parameter.

Comment: @Judo that's why I asked you "So make sure when you are retrieving the tag from db in your code you are using the same datacontext as you are using when calling SaveChanges"

Comment: Just to note, since I stumbled here -- if you're **abstracting the context behind a Repository pattern** make sure that you can correctly **share the context via injection/factory**.  But if you share the context across methods/scopes you could run into problems where **failed commits break subsequent unrelated commits** -- something like this "undo" method could help? http://rundevrun.blogspot.com/2012/06/entity-framework-removing-failed.html

Comment: @FernandoTorres This means that you have not just a single Tag object, but a sequence of them (retrieved from a checkbox list from UI, for example). So you just have to make such operation of adding Tag inside a loop.

Answer (score 0):

How do you go about creating new tags? And how do you attach the existing or created entity to the the article.

Use something like

```
Article a = new Article(...);
a.tags.add(GetOrLoadTag("some tag"));
```

Read this article http://thedatafarm.com/blog/data-access/inserting-many-to-many-relationships-in-ef-with-or-without-a-join-entity/

Comment: If a Tag exists I just add it using article.Tag.Add(existingTag). But when I attempt to save it throws the Primary key violation error.

Comment: When it's a exsisting tag you need to let the framework know it's a exsisting entity. The framework is trying to insert the entity again.

And please make sure you have set the identity column on the primary key.

Comment: Ok, so how do I let the framework know its an existing entity?

Comment: Set the primary key field as INT IDENTITY and see if it works?

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1173001/new-object-in-the-entity-framework-problems-with-primary-key

Comment: I had that before and no difference. Can't see any reason for that to work, its not an issue of creating a unique primary key its an issue of  creating a relationship between the new object and an existing object.

Comment: Can you please provide the full code and database schema? If it was a relationship issue it would throw a foreign key constraint error. But seems like your context is thinking you are putting a new entity in while it's already in the db.

So make sure when you are retrieving the tag from db in your code you are using the same datacontext as you are using when calling SaveChanges.