# How to add entries for many to many relation table with Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, sqlite, foreign-keys, many-to-many, foreign-key-relationship

I have a database with three tables: `Word`, `Idiom`, `WordIdiom` that stores many to many relation between this two tables. `WordItem` includes only foreign keys for `Word` and `Idiom` tables.

After that, I have created Entity model, based on database. I have filled two tables with relevant content, and now I want to add cross-links between these tables.

So, I have written this code:

```
using (var db = new IdiomsDictionaryEntities())
{
    var allIdioms = from idiom in db.Idioms select idiom;

    foreach (var idiom in allIdioms)
    {
        string[] words = idiom.IdiomText.Split(new[] { " ", "-" }, StringSplitOptions.None);

        foreach (var word in words)
        {
            var wordItem = db.Words.SingleOrDefault(exWord => exWord.WordString.ToLower().Equals(word));
            if (wordItem == null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Idiom: " + idiom.IdiomText + ", missing word: " + word);
                continue;
            }

            idiom.Words.Add(wordItem);

            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

But when I run this code, I'm getting following error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll
>   Additional information: An error occurred while saving entities that do not expose foreign key properties for their relationships. The EntityEntries property will return null because a single entity cannot be identified as the source of the exception. Handling of exceptions while saving can be made easier by exposing foreign key properties in your entity types. See the InnerException for details.

Inner-inner exception:

> Unable to update the EntitySet 'WordIdiomMatch' because it has a DefiningQuery and no  element exists in the  element to support the current operation.`

As it is my first time with Entity Framework, I'm really don't know how to fix this. I have tried to add `[ForeignKey()]` property to Entity Framework models, but probably have done it wrong. I have also tried to add a primary key for `WordIdiom`, but it brakes even more things, as in this case I cannot even add items to `Word` and `Idiom` tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the problems, with help of @KerryRandolph and @AntoinePelletier

I was trying to update entities derived from a many-to-many relationship using `Pure Join Table` - meaning no other columns except foreign keys are allowed.
If you add a `Primary Key` column to a `Join Table`, you lose all of the entity framework advantages and have to implement insertion operation manually.

Proper solution was to alter the join table on the DB to make a PK that includes BOTH of the foreign ID columns.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, i see that you have 2 add() for the same purpose. Witch is wrong. Imagine what it would look like in the data base :

```
wordItem.Idioms.Add(idiom);
```

ok now X and Y are linked by the link table as "X-Y" record.

```
idiom.Words.Add(wordItem);
```

And now... it would create another record that link these as "Y-X" witch is useles, if there is already an "X-Y" record then X is linked to Y with this single record and the other way around too.

And i'd say... usualy the primary key of a link table is the combination of the two foreign keys it contain, so the double add would crash anyway.

Comment: Thanks, I have removed duplicate add() command, but the error still persists.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6823947/adding-item-with-many-to-many-relationship-in-entity-framework   this solve most of many to many problems

Comment: Can you, please, elaborate, what exactly I'm missing from the link you have provided,  cause I cannot see anything that I do differently from accepted answer.

Comment: Ho, yeah, sorry, it looks like entity absolutely want a primary key after all, i've been looking into this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7583770/unable-to-update-the-entityset-because-it-has-a-definingquery-and-no-updatefu      and belive me, i'm trying to help you