# Entity Framework assign existing child to parent on a many-to-many relation

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I want to assign a list of EXISTING CHILD obj Days to Course. But Im getting pk issues or duplicated rows. Since Days can be checked or unchecked, I should remove all first and finally add all.

```
Course()
{
  int Id {get;set;}
  string Descripcion {get;set;}
  List<DayOfWeek> Days {get;set;}
}

DayOfWeek()
{
 int Id {get;set;}
 string Name {get;set;}
 List<Course> Courses {get;set;} //Just for Entity Framework to create the many-to-many relation
}
```

SOME OTHER INFO

> - code first
> - lazy loading
> - disconnected (repository/servide webapi layer, UI layer)
> - entities and dto objects, e.g. Course is mapped to UI on CourseData and viceversa.

**When I Attach a new object, it is set as ADDED, I need to fix that**

Comment: You don't show the code you want to fix.

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14307838/entity-framework-adding-existing-child-poco-to-new-parent-poco-creates-new-chi) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6823947/adding-item-with-many-to-many-relationship-in-entity-framework) and post the update code you are trying.

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend to map your foreign key in DayOfWeek entity:

```
DayOfWeek()
{
 int Id {get;set;}
 int CourseId {get;set;}
 string Name {get;set;}
}
```

Then you can do:

```
context.Set<Course>().Add(course);
dayOfWeek.CourseId = course.Id;
context.Set<DayOfWeek>().Attach(dayOfWeek);
context.Entry(dayOfWeek).State = EntityState.Modified;
context.SaveChanges();
```

If you map your foreign keys, then your life is easier with EF.

Comment: Also check this post for more information: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25441027/how-do-i-stop-entity-framework-from-trying-to-save-insert-child-objects

Comment: Thanks but it is a many-to-many relation.... e.g. on Monday you can have Course1 and Course2

Comment: The M:N table is auto created by Entity Framework and it is not visible at the code level (I will add the Courses colection inside DayOfWeek for this to be clearer) thanks

Comment: Yes, but you can create your custom mapping like here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7050404/create-code-first-many-to-many-with-additional-fields-in-association-table